# How to render HTML tags in Html.EditorFor in mvc 4 razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have one property named Description in my class.
I am having value in it some thing like this

```
Object.Description = "<b>Hello</b>";
```

Now I am showing this in view page using Html.EditorFor

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Object.Description);
```

This is showing text as `"<b>Hello</b>"` instead of showing "Hello" in bold.
i.e. it is not rendering HTML tags.

I know that I can render HTML tags like this

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Object.Description));
```

But how to use it with EditorFor HTML helper so that I can show all rendered content in textarea ?

Note: I am using http://jqueryte.com/ for showing editor for textarea.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error;( works in my solution [link]https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=699407CFD03376AD!107&authkey=!APUhz509RyRG8iU&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: May be I was I am missing  [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)] annotation

Answer (score 0):

Textareas do not render HTML or accept any content styling. They encode all HTML characters. You'd need to use a plugin to make your textarea APPEAR to bold text via CSS trickery.

Comment: In that case you'd need to create a custom HTML Editor Template partial view that invokes `jqueryte` on your `Description`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case html.editorfor and showing content on other page:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(abouts[0].Description))
```